# PC's specifications needed to operate Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, specifications, virtual-reality

I'm in the process of making a virtual reality game using Unity3D dp and I'm wondering about the PC's specifications needed to operate Unity3D on it?
any help? :D

Comment: Googling for [Unity System Requirements](https://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements) yields the answer rather quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its Oculus VR, they have high recommended specs:

> This is the hardware that we recommend for the full Rift experience:

- NVIDIA GTX 970 / AMD 290 equivalent or greater
- Intel i5-4590 equivalent or greater
- 8GB+ RAM

> Apart from the recommended spec, the Rift will require:

- Windows 7 SP1 or newer
- 2x USB 3.0 ports
- HDMI 1.3 video output supporting a 297MHz clock via a direct output architecture

https://www.oculus.com/en-us/blog/powering-the-rift/

Current laptops are not recommended either:

> GPUs below Nvidia GTX 600 series or AMD Radeon HD 7000 series are not 
>   supported. In addition, laptops typically are not supported well or at all 
>   (especially if they include Nvidia Optimus or AMD Switchable Graphics)

https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=26029